# Cannot change screen brightness in 20.04 using Wayland

Tags: 20.04, brightness, wayland

I have an XPS-15 7590 and I'm using Wayland. I've always had issues with the brightness with this laptop but now that I'm using Wayland, I cannot change the brightness at all. It is at 100% and ruining my eyes. The settings GUI does nothing to the screen brightness.

Comment: Have you considered switching from Wayland to Xrandr which has been used for 35 years?

Comment: I am using 2 external monitors. Wayland is how I am able to keep them at a good resolution. Before that, I've been using Xrandr terminal command to decrease the resolution.

Comment: I have 2 external TVs (1080p and 2160p) plus laptop display 1080p and have been using Xrandr for five years (Ubuntu 16.04) with no problems. The secret wasn't to decrease resolution but rather set zoom to 1.38 in Unity Tweak Tool. Also set font size to 12 in some apps and use xrandr -dpi 144 for apps that aren't high DPI aware like kid3.

Comment: set from command line? for mine https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302851/brightness-key-react-very-slowly-in-acer-swift-3